# Is there a site which has lists of anime/manga/novels and has up-to-date information on release dates?

Tags: resources

I was watching Bodacious Space Pirates and finished it last night. I know there is a movie coming out in 2014 but it feels as if the anime was an adaptation of something.

I searched Anime News Network and it only has the anime and upcoming movie. I looked up on wikipedia and found the anime was an adaptation of the light novel series Miniskirt Space Pirates (ミニスカ宇宙海賊(パイレーツ) Minisuka Pairētsu). However it doesn't list the volumes that have been released or if any has been released in English, the same with the manga.

I am wondering if there is a site which has more complete information than Anime News Network or Wikipedia.

Comment: It's not a compendium of anime/manga/novels but there's [LNDB](http://lndb.info/) for novels.

Comment: @JonLin show can i tell if any have been released in English as i only know Kara no Kyoukai, Miniskirt Space Pirates and Accel World and none of those to my knowledge have been released in english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Baka Updates](http://baka-updates.com/) (for anime) and [MangaUpdates](http://www.mangaupdates.com/) (for manga) constantly update with newly subbed and translated series.

For a chart of all anime releases by season, check out [The Cart Driver](http://thecartdriver.com/charts/).

And last but not least, to keep track of all the series you have viewed, use [My Anime List](http://myanimelist.net/).

This answers the question in your title, however I don't know of any site that particularly keeps track of only English releases. Myanimelist does have the info on English series though, as it will tell you all the voice actors (Japanese, English, etc). This site is probably your best bet for all the information you would want from a series and it definitely has more than wiki and Anime News Network.

For your situation, however, there are currently no manga released as well as no English light novels. The only light novels that exist are in Japanese. Baka Tsuki was looking into translating it, but nothing has been done yet.

I should probably also add that light novels in general are usually not published into an English version. Translators like BakaTsuki will normally take on those projects and if they do translate the series, it is normally posted in the serie's respective wikia.

Comment: when you say Baka Tsuki, are you talking about that baka-updates url you posted?

Comment: Ahh sorry I didn't clarify. BakaTsuki is group of people that translate Japanese light novels into English. Baka Updates is primarily an updates website. It will let you know the latest translated chapter/episode that has been released as well as link you the group that translated it

Comment: Please do not post links to illegal fan-subbing or scanlation sites, unless they are absolutely needed to complement your answer (they don't, in this case). We have removed the links on purpose (a second time now).

Comment: Ahh sorry. I didn't realize those links were not allowed as well as them being purposely removed.